# Apache Camel's load balanced route doesn't work if one of the endpoint stops connecting

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have a scenario in which if my endpoint1 is down, all messages should be routed to endpoint2 or vice versa. In case both are up then messages should be sent in round robin fashion. Can someone please give some idea how to handle this scenario.

```
from(itemFileConfig.getWorkingDir())
                .log("Entered into file consumption part::")
                .autoStartup(true)
                .process(fileProcessor)
                .split(body().tokenize("\n"))
                .loadBalance()
                .roundRobin()
                .to("direct:kafkaPosting1", "direct:kafkaPosting2")
                .end();


from("direct:kafkaPosting1")
                .to("kafka:" + config.getTopicName() + "?" + "brokers=" +
                        config.getBoostStapServers1() + "&" +"serializerClass=" +
                        config.getSerializer())
                .end();



from("direct:kafkaPosting2")
                    .to("kafka:" + config.getTopicName() + "?" + "brokers=" +
                            config.getBoostStapServers2() + "&" +"serializerClass=" +
                            config.getSerializer())
                    .end();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// use load balancer with failover strategy
// 1 = which will try 1 failover attempt before exhausting
// false = do not use Camel error handling
// true = use round robin mode
.loadBalance().failover(1, false, true)
.to("direct:kafkaPosting1").to("direct:kafkaPosting2");
```